# Production of X-Rays for crystallography

Tags: x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

X-Ray diffraction is an important tool for determining the crystal structure of a sample. I believe that monochromatic X-Ray beams are necessary for this kind of experiments, since diffraction patterns are influenced by wavelength (see [Bragg condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law)).

How are X-Ray beams prepared for crystallography?

Comment: [X-Ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube) or for a few special applications a synchrotron.

Comment: How to decouple the continous spectrum of a Xray tube from the monochromatic one?

Comment: The Kα line is typically much more intense than the background so it dominates the emission. You can filter out the background using some suitable diffraction grating but it isn't usually necessary. With a synchrotron, where there are no sharp lines, we use a diffration grating, e.g. a silicon crystal, to select the wavelength we want.

Answer (score 1):

By using another single crystal of known structure as a diffraction grating, specific wavelengths of X-rays can be selectively diffracted out of a continuous X-ray beam and used for studies that require a monochromatic source. Note that monochromatic X-rays are not a necessary requirement for X-ray crystallography. *Laue crystallography* uses broad-spectrum X-rays.